# Android OnTouchListener on Two Views

Tags: android, multi-touch, ontouchlistener

Hi I've tried to search this question but couldn't find anything on it.

I have two views that I've attached an `onTouchListener` to and I want to be able to touch both of them at the same time and do stuff with it. However, I am coming into issues where it doesn't track the pointer index properly. For example, lets say the I have one finger on View A (pointer ID should be 0) and then I put another finger on View B. The pointer ID for this second touch should be 1 but it appears as 0 as there are no current touches in View B. This totally makes sense but this is not the behavior I want.

In essence, I'm trying to find a way to be able to properly track the touches. Is it better to just make a custom view with a touchlistener that encompasses both View A and View B or is there no real way to get past this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: hve you tried to dispatching `TouchEvent`? Main "cover" `View` on top of all na programmatically check position and index?

Comment: @snachmsm for what I am designing, this isn't what I am looking for/practical. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CustomView is a better approach since the behavior you are expecting is not so common and there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: Hi rupesh, is it possible to have a touch listener on a layout or viewgroup of the two views? That way it can track finger touch #'s and keep track of which view it is in?

Comment: I figured out it out through custom views, thanks! checked for correct answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a real way 
*i am close to sleeping so i can give you concrete code, just logic*

This is what you can do you can copy the `TouchEvent` then you increase the pointer id `++` you get the distance between View A and View B and you subtract it from its x and y and you pass it to View B.

i do not know if that is what you want

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I am not looking for the distance between the two views. Just to clarify, I would be keeping track of the pointer ids? (Aka finger touches)